# null space and Image of $V$ are finite dimensional, prove that $V$ is finite dimensional

Tags: vector-spaces

This seems so easy, but I don't see what I'm supposed to do.

IF V IS FINITE DIMENSIONAL, then we know the $\dim(V) = \dim(\operatorname{nullspace}(V)) + \dim(\operatorname{Image}(V))$.

But this doesn't help me. So what should my next move be?

Comment: The formula actually holds also for infinite-dimensional spaces. Look at the proof of that formula for finite-dimensional $V$ and see how you can modify it to prove finite-dimensionality of $V$ from the premises.

Comment: @DanielFischer The proof assumes that V is finite dimensional. So I don't see how you can just modify it. In fact, the proof I'm looking at crucially relies on the fact that V is finite dimensional.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean there is a linear map $f:V'\to V$ and $\dim{\operatorname{im}f}$ and $\dim\ker f$ are finite?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff this is how I interpreted the question, and I began to wonder what it means for an operator V to be finite dimensional.  Couldn't find a definition online.  I tried defining it with an eigenvalue approach below, and no one has said I'm wrong; but I feel unsure.  Would you be able to comment?

Comment: @BettyMock: In my opinion the most likely interpretation of the OP's question is that in some of the places s/he has written $V$ s/he meant to write $T$ (or at any rate, some other letter to denote a linear transformation).  Indeed, if $T: V \rightarrow V'$ is any linear transformation of vector spaces, then $\operatorname{dim} V = \operatorname{dim} (\operatorname{nullspace}(T)) + \operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{image}(T))$.  Daniel Fischer's answer is a correct answer to this question.

Comment: Perhaps the skill I need to develop is in interpreting the questions.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\mathcal{B}_0 = \{ w_1,\dotsc,w_n\}$ be a basis of the image of the linear map $T$ - no problem since by assumption $\dim \operatorname{im} T < \infty$. For each $i$, choose $v_i$ with $Tv_i = w_i$. Let $\mathcal{B}_1 = \{v_1,\dotsc,\,v_n\}$. Let $\mathcal{B}_2 = \{ k_1,\dotsc,k_m\}$ be a basis of $\ker T$ - no problem since by assumption $\dim \ker T < \infty$.

Show that $\mathcal{B} = \mathcal{B}_1 \cup \mathcal{B}_2$ generates $V$. (It is, in fact, a basis, but we don't need that.)

Let $v \in V$. Then there are $c_1,\dotsc,c_n$ with

$$Tv = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i\cdot w_i,$$

since $\mathcal{B}_0$ is a basis of $\operatorname{im} T$.

Then consider

$$v' = v - \sum_{i=1}^n c_i\cdot v_i.$$

Comment: essentially, you restated the problem that I'm having.

Comment: what i'm asking is how to go about showing this last part.

Comment: You don't see how to continue? I'll expand a bit.

Comment: Can you see it now?

Comment: uhh... what? I'm now more confused.

Comment: By what? If you can explain your confusion, maybe I can help getting rid of it.

Comment: what the heck is v' and why are we subtracting. In short, what does this formula have to do with the proof.

Comment: We want to show that $v$ can be written as a linear combination of the $v_i$ and the $k_j$. Applying $T$ gives the coefficients of the $v_i$. So what remains - $v'$ - should be in $\ker T$.

Comment: I don't know if I follow you because I still don't know what the last formula has to do with anything.

Comment: What is $T(v')$?

Comment: I have no idea because i don't know what v' is.

Comment: It's the vector defined in the last line. $v' = v - \sum\limits_{i=1}^n c_iv_i$.

Comment: That has absolutely no meaning to me. So, in short, I have no idea what T(v') is.

Comment: $$T\left(v - \sum_{i=1}^n c_i v_i\right) = T(v) - \sum_{i=1}^n c_iT(v_i).$$

Comment: T(v_i) = c_i*w_i. So the summation on RHS is (c_i)^2w_i? I'm still not sure I follow you.

Comment: No, $T(v_i) = w_i$. So no squares.

Comment: Why does T(v_i) = w_i?

Comment: Because we chose the $v_i$ that way. We need a system that maps to a basis of the image. So we pick a basis of the image, and for each basis vector $w_i$ in the image, we choose a $v_i \in V$ with $T(v_i) = w_i$.

Comment: Tv = sum c_i * w_i. so why doesn't this mean that Tv = c_i*w_i.

Comment: I don't understand that question. $Tv$ is a vector in the image. Hence it can be written - in a unique way - as a linear combination of the basis vectors. Knowing the coefficients, we can construct another vector in $V$ that is mapped to the same vector in the image.

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusing issue is "what do we mean that V is finite dimensional"?  We talk about sets of "vectors" being finite dimensional, but V isn't a set of vectors, it is a linear operator.  And even in finite spaces, we are simply saying that dim(nullspace) + dim(image) = dim(entire space), not that V is finite dimensional.

Let's say V is finite if it has a finite number of eigenvalues of finite multiplicity.

We'll start by looking at the eigenvectors of V.  None of them map into the nullspace, so they must map into the image space {Vx} of dimension n.  Let {y} be the set of eigenvectors of V.  Then the vector space {Vy} $\subset$ {Vx} is finite dimensional.

For every distinct eigenvalue $\lambda \ne 0$ there is a subspace of generalized eigenvectors which is linearly independent from all the eigenvectors whose associated eigenvalue is not $\lambda$.  Let {$v_1$} be the subspace of generalized eigenvectors associated with  $\lambda$.  As in the finite dimensional case, we will consider that the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\lambda$ is dim{$v_1$}.

If {Vx} is finite dimensional, there can only be a finite number of these sets {V$x_i$}, so there can only be a finite number of eigenvalues of V and all the multiplicities must be finite.

We are not quite done -- we must look at the eigenvalue 0.  Since nullspace(V) is of finite dimension, the multiplicity of 0 has to be finite.

So now we have shown that V has a finite set of eigenvalues with finite multiplicity.  That fills our definition of finite.

---

It may be that V is defined as "finite" if it is isomorphic to a finite matrix.  That can be proved also based on the hypotheses, but it gets kind of complicated, and involves digging into the structure of generalized eigenvectors.  At least it does for me.  Hopefully the "finite eigenvalues" definition will serve.

Comment: Since you asked for comments on your answer: it is not really clear what a "finite dimensional operator" should mean.  Probably most mathematicians would try to correct that to "finite rank operator", i.e., for which the image is finite-dimensional.  When working with vector spaces in general -- i.e., over a field which need not be algebraically closed -- eigenvalue arguments will not be sufficient (because there are nontrivial linear transformations which have no eigenvalues and hence no nontrivial generalized eigenspaces) and should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks.  I've never worked with a space that was not closed.  Pretty much I've been restricted to L$p$ Banach spaces.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood what I meant.  I was talking about the *field of scalars* being algebraically closed, e.g. $\mathbb{C}$.  Even over $\mathbb{R}$ a linear endomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ need not have an eigenvalue: take a direct sum of rotations.  But there are other issues as well: even over $\mathbb{C}$, a linear endomorphism of an infinite-dimensional vector space need not even have any nonzero finite-dimensional invariant subspaces.  See Exercise 1.11 here: http://math.uga.edu/~pete/invariant_subspaces.pdf.

Comment: Or note that more simply the endomorphism on a vector space (over any scalar field; take $\mathbb{C}$ if you like) with basis $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ given by $T(e_i) = e_{i+1}$ for all $i$ has no nonzero finite-dimensional invariant subspaces.  But one would certainly not want to call this endomorphism "finite-dimensional".

Comment: @Pete yes you did say it was over a field that was algebraically closed, and yes I misread it.  You seem to be pointing out that a linear operator on an infinite dimensional vector space need not have any finite dimensional invariant subspaces.  Is this not obvious?  In this problem however, we were told that both the image and the nullspace were finite dimensional. So I think my question is: given these hypotheses, will we indeed have eigenvectors?  and will the generalized eigenvectors indeed span the image space?

Comment: I don't know whether it's obvious, but it's true, and if you know it, then good.  The reason I pointed it out is that you proposed a definition "Let's say V is finite if it has a finite number of eigenvalues of finite multiplicity."  My example has no eigenvalues but is presumably not a "finite endomorphism".

Comment: "In this problem however, we were told that both the image and the nullspace were finite dimensional."  Well, okay: if we assume both of these then by the Dimension Theorem we get that the domain of the map is finite-dimensional, so nothing very interesting is going on.  I thought you were trying to give a definition of "finite-dimensional" in general.  If you assume that the domain is finite-dimensional then surely every linear map is "finite-dimensional"?

Comment: (So to answer your question: yes, if $T: V \rightarrow V$ is a linear operator over an algebraically closed field of scalars with both $\operatorname{Ker} T$ and $\operatorname{Image} T$ finite-dimensional, then $V$ is finite-dimensional, so we are in the usual setting of undergraduate linear algebra.  So yes, $V$ is spanned by generalized eigenvectors for $T$.)  Also I just noticed that you are assuming that $T$ is an endomorphism, i.e., $V = V'$, which simplifies things.  It is not clear that the OP is assuming this...but exactly what s/he is assuming is unfortunately not very clear.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark If Img(T) is finite and V is infinite, it would have to be an endomorphism, wouldn't it? In thinking it thru I, like you, concluded that V' finite means there is a full spectrum of eigenvectors of T.  So the eigenvalue approach seems to work in this case.  But we should apply the approach to T, not V, then there is no conclusion that V is finite.  Obviously if it were there would be no problem. That said, it's kind of circuitous whereas Dan's proof is direct.  The OP was having trouble understanding what Dan was saying, so it may be that another approach was useful to him/her.

Comment: An endomorphism is simply a linear map $T: V \rightarrow V'$ with $V' = V$.  This does not follow from any other hypothesis.  In particular, if $V' \neq V$ then it does not make sense to talk about eigenvalues, generalized eigenspaces, invariant subspaces, and so forth.

Comment: There are further confusions in your answer.  You seem to think that the desired conclusion is some kind of "finiteness" property of a linear map.  This is what the OP says, but in my opinion what he must mean is: "Suppose $T: V \rightarrow V'$ is a linear map.  If $\operatorname{Null Space}(T)$ and $\operatorname{Image(T)}$ are finite-dimensional, show that $V$ is finite-dimensional."  This is a form of Rank-Nullity, as proven in Daniel Fischer's answer.

Comment: Since the hypotheses quoted above imply that $V$ is finite-dimensional, in case $V = V'$ they certainly imply the finiteness of the multiplicities of the eigenvalues of $T$.  Moreover, your argument for this weaker conclusion is faulty even under all the assumptions you have imposed: "We'll start by looking at the eigenvectors of V. None of them map into the nullspace." Every element of the nullspace is an eigenvector, so if the nullspace is nonzero then some eigenvectors map into the nullspace.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Yes, Pete,  your interpretation of the question seems entirely correct. It is indeed true that some eigenvectors map into the nullspace, and I'm sorry I said otherwise.  What I was thinking about was the eigenvectors that map into the (non-zero) range.